# posted data do not bind to action parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, post, model-view-controller, data-binding

This is my view

```
    @using System.Web.Optimization
@model IEnumerable<DnDBeginner.Models.User>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h4>Users</h4>
    </div>
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ListUserCharacters", "Players", FormMethod.Post, new { id="UserForm"}))
{
    <input id="userID" type="hidden" />
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                @item.UserName
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-11">
                <span class="link" data-userid="@item.UserID.ToString()">Choose</span>
                <hr />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}

<script>
    $('.link').click(function () {
        $('#userID').val($(this).data('userid'));
        $('#UserForm').submit();
});
    });
</script>
```

And this is my Action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ListUserCharacters(string userID)
    {
        var userCharacters = new { userID = userID };
        return View();
    }
```

The action is accessed successfully but the userID get a null value, so it does not bind to the hidden fields value. What am i missing ? Dont know if its relevant but when i looked at the "network" section of chromes web tools i get a "Request URL:http://localhost:61487/Players/ListUserCharacters
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown" so i am not even sure that the form data are posted successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for taking time to respond to my question.

Well as it turns out the problem was that in the hidden field `<input id="userID" type="hidden" />`, the "name" attribute was required. It appears that when submitting a form, both "id" and "name" attributes of input element(s) are required otherwise the browser will not be able to properly encode the upload data and the request. And that's why i was getting the "Provisional headers are shown" message in the network section of chromes web tools. So this `<input id="userID" name="userID" type="hidden" />` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The post request body should look something like userID='the user id'.  So you should see something in body.  Have you tried adding the 'FromBody'.

```
public ActionResult ListUserCharacters([FromBody]string userID)
{
    var userCharacters = new { userID = userID };
    return View();
}
```

Further if that doesn't fix it you can help debugging to make sure the value is populated on the client with a qualifying statement to make sure #userID has something.

```
    var value = $('#userID').val();
    if (value === '' || value === undefined || value === null) {
        console.log('no value');
    }
    else {
        console.log('value is', value);
        $('#UserForm').submit();
    }
```

Lastly if the value is not getting populated, try to put the span in an "a" element to make the click more reliable.

You can try something like this... not tested on my end.

```
<a href="onclick:$('#userID').val('item.UserID.ToString()'"><span>Choose</span></a>
```